# How do I keep the Resources overlay open while placing roads?

Tags: cities-skylines

Is there a way to keep the resources overlay open when placing roads? I want to put highways around high-resource areas, or join them together sometimes, but every time I select the road tool it switches out of the resources overlay.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a way to keep the resources overlay open when placing roads?

Not with the current base game.

With [this mod](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=410842044&searchtext=resource) you *should* be able to keep resource views toggled on while placing roads.

**Note** that enabling mods will disable your ability to get achievements. (Although [this mod](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=407055819&searchtext=achievement) may re-enable your ability to complete achievements)